# How to Separate string In jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string array in jquery that include:

```js
["$1#Structure$2#Accounting$3Acc#$1Programming"]
```

Now I split string that is after '#' ,then give me result that include:

```js
["Structure","Accounting","Acc","Programming"]
```

Comment: `Accounting$3Acc` where `#`?

Comment: Can you  just elaborate it...

Comment: use `.split('#');` ?

Comment: None of what you have shown is jQuery

Comment: In this case `arr[0].match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just split and remove the first item

```
var items = ["$1#Structure$2#Accounting$3Acc#$1Programming"][0].split(/[#]*\$\d[#]*/);
items.splice(0,1);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var items = ["$1#Structure$2#Accounting$3Acc#$1Programming"][0].split(/[#]*\$\d[#]*/);
items.splice(0,1);
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(items, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Thank U So Much @gurvinder372

Comment: `/#*\$\d#*/` Seems to be working aswell, why do you need the brackets (`[]`) around `#`?

Comment: @Arg0n that is true, but `[#]*` looks more readable to me, so I would prefer to keep it that way.

Comment: Ok,my broblem was in [] @Arg0n ,It's ReSolved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript function called `split()`. You have to pass a split argument into it . Here u want to split by # , so the code will be

```
var strArr=stringvar.split("#");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
"$1#Structure$2#Accounting$3Acc#$1Programming"
.split(new RegExp('[0-9#$ ]+')) // splitting using regex
.filter(function(n){ return n != "" }) // removing empty cells
```

OUTPUT :    **["Structure", "Accounting", "Acc", "Programming"]**

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression with `match` method can be applied on the string to extract the values:

```js
var arr = ["$1#Structure$2#Accounting$3Acc#$1Programming"];
var reg = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;

var newarr = arr[0].match(reg);

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newarr, 0, 0);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```